# Why my subpage is not accesible in Github pages?

Tags: github-pages

I uploaded the files in my main Github pages repository and still cannot see the documented I created when clicked.

I can see the document in the root of the repository, but the page doesn't load for the file in the subfolder: https://isabelmendozap.github.io/cheatsheet/

https://github.com/isabelmendozap/isabelmendozap.github.io/tree/main/cheatsheet